# metatrader 4 installation on ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

how can I install [Metatrader4](https://www.metatrader4.com/en) on Ubuntu 18? I had tried to install the software in a wine virtual box but wasn't able to do so. I'd like to know the exact criteria to go on with so I can be able to use the software as it is in windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use wine follow these [instructions](https://fxgears.com/index.php?threads/howto-easily-install-the-latest-metatrader-4-mt4-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts.1123/). Commands after downloading a broker ([metatrader4](https://pepperstone.com/en/trading-platforms/metatrader-4-win#free-download-link)):

```
sudo apt-get install wine-stable
cd Downloads/
wine pepperstone4setup.exe
```

- [pepperstone4](https://pepperstone.com/en/) is the example use in the link; change it to the broker you used.

Mind though that there is a better and easier method: install virtualBox, windows inside virtualBox and then you can use Windows software natively. Makes for easier backups and is fully sandboxed. It will be a lot smoother experience.